# Asynchronous execution queue in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to a create a "Task Queue" that has the following behaviour.

- Work is added via a Func such that the task is only started when the item is popped off the queue (no when it is added to the queue)
- Only a single item in the queue should be executing at any one time.
- If a new item is added, anything in the queue and the currently executing item (if there is one) should be cancelled, such that the new item can be started ASAP

This is what I have come up with, using Channels

```
public class Execution
{
    private Channel<Func<Task>>? _channel;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationToken;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _lastWorkItemCancellationToken;

    public Task Completion { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;

    public Task Push(Func<CancellationToken, Task> func)
    {
        if (_channel == null) // lazilly create the channel
            StartReader();

        _lastWorkItemCancellationToken?.Cancel();

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();

        _lastWorkItemCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationTokenSource cancelCopy = _lastWorkItemCancellationToken;

        _channel!.Writer.TryWrite(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await func(cancelCopy.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                tcs.TrySetResult();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                tcs.TrySetCanceled(ex.CancellationToken);
                Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private void StartReader()
    {
        _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Func<Task>>();
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Completion = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await foreach (Func<Task> func in _channel.Reader
                    .ReadAllAsync(_cancellationToken.Token))
                {
                    await func().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {

            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Ending Consumer");
        });
    }

    internal void Complete()
    {
        _cancellationToken?.Cancel();
        _channel?.Writer.TryComplete();
    }
}
```

Another requirement is that I do not want the next item in the Queue to be started until I have updated the UI with the current items result. This is an annoying requirement, but is necessary for my particular requirements. To achieve this, I am using `ContinueWith` such that the UI is updated as part of the work of the currently executing item.

The following shows a test app in WPF

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Execution _execution = new();
    private int _count = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);

        _execution.Complete();
        _execution.Completion.Wait(8000);
    }

    private void OnAddSingleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _ = AddWork(_count++);
    }

    private void OnAddMultipleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            _ = AddWork(_count++);
        }
    }

    private void OnCompleteButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _execution.Complete();
    }

    private async Task AddWork(int i)
    {
        try
        {
            var ts = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            await _execution.Push(async (cancel) =>
            {
                await SimulateWorkAsync(i, cancel)
                    .ContinueWith((x) =>
                {
                    UpdateUI(x.Result);
                }, cancel, TaskContinuationOptions.None, ts);
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Content = e.Message;
        }
    }

    private async Task<int> SimulateWorkAsync(int value, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000, cancellation);
        return value + 1;
    }

    private void UpdateUI(int value)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Result.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I could get some feedback on this design, and also if there is any way to also achieve what I want without using `ContinueWith` which feels a bit messy. Ideally, I'll like to be using only `await`.

Comment: You can use a BufferBlock as well. In order to wait for the UI to update, you can simply include that operation as part of the Task that is being queued in your queue. In order to update the UI, you will need to dispatch the operation on the UI Thread anyway, and this operation should be awaitable nowadays.

Comment: Small nit pick - given your requirements you don't need a queue. There are only ever a max of two items: A running item (which may be cancelling) and a waiting item. If a third item arrives it deletes the waiting item (its can't really cancel it since it isn't running) and the third item replaces the second in the waiting slot. The first item will already be cancelling since the second item cancelled the first.

Comment: @Ccm I'll look into BufferBlock, is there any benefit over the Continuewith?

Comment: @DavidT yes, you're right, I don't need a Queue, but I thought it would be easier to use something that already handles all the locking operations.  I think if I was to implement it myself, I'd need a Semaphore such that only one thing is running at a time, which I believe is basically what channels is doing

Comment: @wforl I agree with DavidT. You don't need it. You don't need locking either. If this is a WinForms app, it uses a [WindowsFormSynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) which is already doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This belongs to stackoverflow btw.
You can fix your UI update problem like so. The work item in your queue should expire when the operation on the Dispatcher (updating the UI thread) is done. This solves your ContinueWith design conundrum.

```
private async Task AddWork(int i)
{
    try
    {
        await _execution.Push(async (cancel) =>
        {
           var x = await SimulateWorkAsync(i, cancel);
           await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=>{
                UpdateUI(x);}, ..., cancel);
           
        });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Content = e.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I guess the problem with using Dispatcher is that you can't really use it from a ViewModel, unless you do something like Application.Current.Dispatcher, which then won't work from a Test. Or you have some kind of IDispatcher service. Whenever I post a design/feedback question on SO, it gets closed as they say its not for that

Comment: @wforl unless you want to completely forgo multithreading, you should have the Dispatcher available in the ViewModel anyway. It is a necessary tradeoff